# as3 constant variable generation on compile

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, compilation

Is it possible to generate a (constant) variable on compile time, which  from then on will always remain the same during runtime.

For example, is it possible to write a piece of code that generates a version number based on the current date on compile time, but from then on always remains the same, even on different dates, only to change when a new version is compiled.

Thanks in advance,

Citiral.

Answer (score 2):

i use an external tool like Apache ANT to do the job and versionize my code:

```
<!--
Get the current date & time
-->
<tstamp>
<format property="build.time" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa" locale="en,UK"/>
</tstamp>
```

Then i put it into a class outside my classpath and exchange it with the equivalent in my classpath (here my Version.as class)

```
<!--
Copy the template file and replace %BUILDTIME%
-->
<copy file="src/Version.as" tofile="src/as/de/client/project/utils/Version.as" overwrite="true" />
<replace file="src/as/de/client/project/utils/Version.as" token="%BUILDTIME%" value="${build.time}" />
</target>
```

this is the content of the template Version.as which will replace the Version.as class in your classpath:

```
package de.client.project.utils
{
public class Version
{
    public static const BUILD_TIME      : String = "%BUILDTIME%";
}
}
```

then you simply have to trace the constant in your code at startup:

```
trace("Version: " + Version.BUILD_TIME);
```

regards.Rob